How to prioritize the jobs in Publishing service queue?
We would like to prioritize some of jobs to be published quickly in Publishing service.
Could you please share some tips if that feature available?

I don't believe there is an out of the box way to do this.

You can try the below code and set the job priority. It is possible by thread priority.
var options = new DefaultJobOptions({your parameters});
//var options = new DefaultJobOptions("JobName", "Category", "WebsiteName", jobAction.Target, jobAction.Method.Name, null);
options.Priority = System.Threading.ThreadPriority.Lowest;
JobManager.Start(options);

Priority can be Lowest, BelowNormal, Normal, AboveNormal, and Highest.
See the blog post for more details: Jobs in Sitecore
